# Pass file to save to php

Tags: javascript, php, header, save, readfile

I have this php file:

```
<?php
$file = 'ico/people.gif';
if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

This works.

But the line `$file = 'ico/people.gif';` should be removed, and instead the script is to receive the url from another document.

This other document has this JavaScript in header:

```
<script>
  function save_file(url){
    document.location.href = "save.php?image="+url;
  }
</script>
```

And this button in body:

```
<input type="button" onclick="save_file('ico/people.gif')" value="Save image">
```

How can I make this work together?

people.gif is just an example. It should, when I get it to work, be replaced by a string, that can represent any image.

Basically, all I want is a save image button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$file = $_GET['image'];
```

instead of your first line should do it.

Comment: Sure did. Thanks a lot. I'll try to make it work with variable now.